# How to make a module installable in Magento?

Tags: magento, installation, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I have successfully created a custom payment gateway module in Magento. Everything work fine as expected.

What I want to do is to make the module installable so that anyone who has the `.zip` file can install it rather than coping the files manually. I know this is possible with magento and I have seen such modules.

How to make the module installable in Magento which already has been developed ? Please explain the steps if possible.

Comment: There is a new Stackoverflow site for Magento: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the step-by-step instruction on how to Package an Extension.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/packaging_a_magento_extension

Let me know if you run in any trouble.

Firstly, go to your `Admin > System > Magento Connect > Package Extensions`
There you will be greeted with `New Extension` where you can fill all the details of your module.
If you don't understand any field there, just check it in the above article which gives explanation of all the fields required while packaging an extension.

Comment: can please explain the Extension key part. Kind of unclear to me.

Comment: Extension key is the key we use to install an extension. You don't need to worry about it at this point. Start reading and implementing from `Packaging an extension` section

Comment: It does not tell you how to package step by step. can please provide me the steps

Comment: I get "There was a problem saving package data" error. I did according to the documentation. Why is that

Comment: @Dasun There should not be a space in the module name. Hope this helps